# Isomorphism of stalks and the complement of the exceptional locus.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Qing Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry, and on pg. 272, the proof of
**lemma 2.20 b)** there is a certain part I don't get.

Let $X,Y$ be Noetherian integral schemes and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a separated birational morphism of finite type. Let $ x \in X$ be such that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ where $y=f(x)$ is an isomorphism. I want to show that $$X \times_Y \text{ Spec } \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \rightarrow \text{Spec } \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$$
is an isomorphism.

I have no idea how to do this, Liu says one uses an argument similar to the one one uses to show that there is a non-empty open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism. To show that, one basically notes that there are non-empty open subsets $U,V$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively such that $f_U : U \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism. Then one uses that $f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow V$ is separated and admits a section $V \cong U \subset Y$ to show that $U$ is clopen in $f^{-1}(V).$ Thus, by the irreducility of $f^{-1}(V)$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)=V$ is isomorphic to $V$.

I don't see how to reproduce this proof, or use a similar argument to show the above unfortunately. Could someone help me?

Comment: Terve! Systeemi tuotti moderaattoreille hälytyksen, että olet deletoinut aika lailla kysymyksiäsi. Katselin niitä, ja ilmeisesti millään deletoimallasi ei ollut yhtään plusääniä saanutta vastausta, joten ei kai tässä mitään ihmeempää hämminkiä. Toistaiseksi siis ihan vaan tiedoksi, että tämmöistäkin isoveli tarkkatilee :-). Itse kysymyksissä ei mielestäni ole mitään vikaa, joten ne voisi yhtä hyvin jättää näkyviin. En osaa valitettavasti auttaa vastaamisessa, kun AG:stä tunnen vain alkeita.